# Greenshot does not work in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Anyone know why you cannot use Greenshot in Visual Studio? I hit the Screen Print button and it does not bring up the cross-hairs to drag my window size. Instead it just takes a plain windows screenshot. I looked for keyboard commands that might override it but didnt see anything at first glance. It works for every other program but not when Visual Studio is the active window.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It's because your visual studio is running in a higher level (permission wise) than your greenshot instance.

for a one time test, close Greenshot, and run it as administrator (right click on the file, run as administrator).

As a more permanent solution, you can just set the compatibility mode for the file to be run in admin mode, and then when it's started on start up it should capture your VS instances as well :).

[image: run as admin]

**Edit:**
Just in case, you can easily figure out if anything else is wired to a shortcut by doing the following:

[image: figure out who's using a shortcut]

Comment: I dont believe this is the case. I tried your method and it didnt work. I think that VS is trying to consume the F12 command key.

Comment: F12 !? why don't you use the "print screen" ? F12 is probably being set as a shortcut in VS, usually it resolves to navigate to if my memory serves me right (or maybe that's the resharper override ... will have to check).

Comment: Doh! I guess I was not fully awake when I responsed yesterday. I have no idea why I was trying to use F12. That works actually. I just need to require Greenshot to run as admin. Simple solution I never thought about. Thank you!

Comment: Woah, this has been bugging me for a while!  Thanks for the solution.

Comment: this solution is applicable for Lightshot as well, and maybe in general for all similar products

Comment: @Vladislav make sense ... same principals :)

Comment: I feel like this gave a solution to the wrong problem.  Why is visual studio eating the PrintScreen key.  You can't plug it in like you showed as a shortcut, it won't even allow it used there.  It's like Visual Studio just sucks up that keystroke and doesn't let you use it.

Comment: This applies to Snagit as well. Thank you.

Comment: @Nick  . glad it helped.